# Differences between LEGACY schema and Data Studio Apps Script Service

Tags: looker-studio, getschema

I'm having problems trying to migrate from legacy schema object to new Data Studio Apps Script Service.

For example in my old schema object I have this dimension:

```
  {
    "name" : "datetxt",
    "label" : "Date",
    "description" : "date of sale",
    "dataType" : "STRING",
    "group" : "Dates",
    "semantics" : {
      "conceptType" : "DIMENSION",
      "semanticGroup" : "DATETIME",
      "semanticType " : "YEAR_MONTH_DAY",
      "isReaggregatable" : false
    }
  }
```

When using the new method I translate it this way:

```
 var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
 var fields = cc.getFields();      
 var types = cc.FieldType;
 var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;

[...]

fields.newDimension()
      .setId('datetxt')
      .setName('Date')
      .setDescription('date of sale')
      .setGroup('Dates')                /* or types.DATETIME ???*/
      .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY)    /* or types.TEXT ??? */        
      .setIsReaggregatable(false)
```

the documentation is not clear enough in which group and type should I use when declaring the object with the new way.
Can anyone help?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code looks correct. We got rid of needing to separately set `dataType` and `semanticType` since a semantic type always maps to a specific `dataType`.

Groups are user-defined & just there so Data Studio can group like fields together in some parts of the UI. Typically, groups are more useful if you have a very large number of fields.